# Angular variable manipulation from different directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a bit struggling with infinite scroll in angular. I have one object array where all items are stored in. This object is part of directive controller.

Now when I am trying to implement infinite scroll I use separate directive to calculate offsets. I would like to access from this scroll directive variable from the other directive where object array is defined.

How can I do this? What would be the easiest way here? I am searching for week and can't find anything easy enough to implement to my solution. 
Thank you

Comment: You haven't marked my answer as accepted. Is there something insufficient that I need to clarify for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the directive's `require` property to get the `$scope` of another directive's controller, or use the parent controller of the directives to pass in a shared value. Here's an example using `require` [**(live demo)**](http://jsbin.com/kofirinoka/2/edit?html,js,output).

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <foo></foo>
  <bar></bar>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.foo = 123;
    }
  };
})
.directive('bar', function() {
  return {
    require: '^foo',
    controller: function($scope) {
      console.log($scope.foo);
    }
  };
})
;
```

The timing for this next example may not be what you want. They are sharing the same variable, but changes to `$scope` in the first directive's controller won't be applied until after the second directive's controller has already run. [**(live demo).**](http://jsbin.com/kulehudihe/2/edit?html,js,output)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{sharedValue}}
  <foo shared-value="sharedValue"></foo>
  <bar shared-value="sharedValue"></bar>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sharedValue = 'abc';
})
.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      sharedValue: "="
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      console.log($scope.sharedValue); // abc
      $scope.sharedValue = 123;
    }
  };
})
.directive('bar', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      sharedValue: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      console.log($scope.sharedValue); // still abc, will update later
    }
  };
})
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it necessary to use $scope in order to pass variable? For example I don't have $scope in my controller and instead I use this.variable

Comment: @user007 Yes. In the first example, the directives are sharing the same `$scope`. In the second example, they have their own scopes, but both scopes have access to the same variable.